# Read incoming SMS in nuxt

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, nuxt.js

In a nuxt app (using cordova to convert to native app) what is the best way to read an incoming SMS and relay that SMS to an api?

If its not possible in the nuxt, is the a way to configure this in, lets say maybe, xml manifest after its converted by cordova

Use case: 
The app monitors when the OTP SMS is received by the user 
App checks the format of SMS and its a match it authenticates the OTP without user manually entering OTP

I tried [this solution](https://medium.com/@hanatharesh2712/how-to-get-sms-text-in-ionic-cordova-app-without-the-need-permissions-of-android-using-sms-f60f56094d15) but error cannot read `plugin of undefined in window.cordova.plugins.smsRetriever`

Answer (score 0):

Android [has recently blocked](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/10/providing-safe-and-secure-experience.html) the retrieval of SMS for any app that has not been explicitly approved by them to do so, due to privacy concerns, rendering obsolete those SMS plugins:

> As part of today's Google Play Developer Policy update, we're
>   announcing changes related to SMS and Call Log permissions. Some
>   Android apps ask for permission to access a user's phone (including
>   call logs) and SMS data. Going forward, **Google Play will limit which
>   apps are allowed to ask for these permissions**. Only an app that has
>   been selected as a user's default app for making calls or text
>   messages will be able to access call logs and SMS, respectively.

That's why they have created the [SMS Retriever API](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/overview), which does not require SMS permission, instead it relies in the 11 character **hash** found in the SMS that is created based on your app's signature. Whenever you send an SMS with this hash, its contents will be handled to your app.

Here's a Cordova plugin I've created to use the SMS Retriever API, with an example app:

[**cordova-plugin-sms-retriever**](https://github.com/andreszs/cordova-plugin-sms-retriever)

[image]